# problem in calling webservice from another class

Tags: iphone, web-services, json

this is my class

```
#import "newsFeedController.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//statements
webService = [[WebServiceManager alloc] init];
    [webService setDelegate:self];
//am calling the webservicemanager class here
    [webService userStatusUpdateGet:@"1" endLimit:@"10" setSessionID:[[UserSession getInstance] SESSION_ID]];
//am printing.....
nslog(@"printing result %@",webService.test);
```

this test is a array from `webServiceManager` class that has to return only after going to
- `(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method

how do I do this?.Thanks

(am using json request and response)

Comment: can you please give more and formated information

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` a delegate method of WebServiceManager? If yes it should be accessible within your class where you can implement the method's action

Answer (score 0):

Create a protocol for your view controllers to conform to, for callbacks when the data is retrieved. The view controller implementation will refresh display as appropriate.

EDIT:

Create a protocol:

```
@protocol WebServiceDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) serviceSuccessful: (BOOL)success withData:(NSMutableData*)data;
```

Create a class with delegate object of this protocol. Also create a method in this class which would be called by your viewController to start setting up the connection:

```
@interface WebServiceHandler : NSObject {

id <WebServiceDelegate> delegate;}
```

Write all the connection delegate method implementation in WebServiceHandler class. In connectionDidFinishLoading, set the delegate object:

```
[[self delegate] serviceSuccessful:YES withData:webData];
```

Make your viewController conform to WebServiceDelegate protocol and give an implementation to serviceSuccessful method. Now this method would be called in the viewController, as soon as WebServiceHandler class has finished with retreiving data from the connection.

Comment: Create a protocol for your view controllers to conform to, for callbacks when the data is retrieved. The view controller implementation will refresh display as appropriate How to do tis?can you xplain it step by step

Comment: i can't get you.Can you tell me with my example ??

Comment: Refer the tutorial given here:  http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html